# View draw by CoreGraphic disappears after app goto background for a while

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

Here is the code of my view.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let path = self.getPath()

    path.stroke()
}

func getPath() -> UIBezierPath {

    let path = UIBezierPath()

    path.lineWidth = 1
    path.lineCapStyle = .round
    path.lineJoinStyle = .round
    mainColor.setStroke()
    mainColor.setFill()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0,y:0))

    path.addQuadCurve(to: endPointLeft, controlPoint: controlPointLeft)
    path.addLine(to: startPointRight)
    path.addQuadCurve(to: endPointRight, controlPoint: controlPointRight)
    path.addLine(to: startPointLeft)

    path.fill()
    path.stroke()

    return path
}
```

It works fine. But sometimes after get into background for a while, this view will be disappeared.

***** More Info *****

In the ViewController has a feature that scrolling changes the height's of this view.
After changing the constraint of height, call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is relayout subviews when application did become active for that first add observer like below in your controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
}

@objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification:Notification)
{
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: try layoutsubviews methos

Answer (score 0):

Reason:

After stay in BG for a long time, it will call draw() function to redraw the View.
And as if the height of view is 0, it will draw nothing.

Solution:

Use CAShapeLayer to update the path.

```
@IBInspectable var mainColor: UIColor = UIColor.blue

private var bottomLayer : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    bottomLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    bottomLayer.strokeColor = mainColor.cgColor
    bottomLayer.fillColor = mainColor.cgColor
    bottomLayer.lineWidth = 1
    bottomLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    bottomLayer.path = self.getPath().cgPath

    self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLayer)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.bottomLayer.frame = self.bounds
    self.bottomLayer.path = self.getPath().cgPath
}
```